# The output of a program is not coming it is a linked list program

Tags: c++

This a code of a linked list there is no syntax error but  expected output not coming this is an insertion of linkList item program and print all linked list node.

I don't know whether insertion function working properly or not because of this only prints 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node {
  int data;
  struct node* next;
};

struct node* creation(int value) {
  struct node* acc;
  acc = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  acc->data = value;
  acc->next = NULL;
  return acc;
}

struct node* insertion(int value, struct node* root1) {
  if (root1 == NULL) {
    root1 = creation(value);
  }
  if (root1 != NULL) {
    root1 = root1->next;

    root1 = creation(value);
  }
  return root1;
}
// This is a int main function
int main() {
  struct node* root = NULL;
  struct node* star = NULL;
  star = root = insertion(1, root);
  insertion(2, root);
  insertion(3, root);

  while (star != NULL) {
    printf("%d", star->data);
    star = star->next;
  }
}
```

The output of a program coming is

```
1
```

But expected output is

```
1 2 3
```

this only shows `1`. Help me to solve this problem

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Your code is not C, but only because of `#include <iostream>` and
`using namespace std;`. You wrote the rest of the code as if you were writing C. You are doing several things that you should not do in C++: 1. use `struct` before a type name in a variable declaration or return type. It is not required in C++ and may cause name lookup/scoping issues, 2. using `malloc` instead of `new`, 3. using `printf` instead of `cout <<`, etc. Are you sure that whatever your study course/material is trying to teach you C++ and not C?

Comment: But compiler works on this situation

Comment: It happens to work in this case, but e.g. `malloc` instead of `new` most often causes undefined behavior in C++ (in this case it technically does as well). And even if it works, you are not learning proper C++ style, but C style (or neither).

Comment: Could you add an explanation of why this code should work? Actually, you don't really need to add it, but go through the code yourself, line by line, and explain to yourself (or [to a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)) why your code does exactly what you want it to do and why what you want it to do is correct. Pay particular attention to explaining why your list grows longer than 1 node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have logic flaws in your `insertion` function.

First of, you only want *either* of the two `if` branches to be taken, so the second one should not be using `if`, but `else`. Otherwise `root1` could be `NULL` first, but then non-`NULL` after the first `if` statement.

Secondly, you need to assign the new node in the second branch to the `next` pointer of the structure, not a pointer variable local to the `insertion` function.

Lastly, you are not setting `root` properly from the return value in `main`:

```
node* insertion(int value, node* root1) {
  if (root1 == nullptr) {
    root1 = creation(value);
  } else {
    root1->next = creation(value);
    root1 = root1->next;
  }
  return root1;
}
// This is a int main function
int main() {
  node* root = nullptr;
  node* star = nullptr;
  star = root = insertion(1, root);
  root = insertion(2, root);
  root = insertion(3, root);

  while (star != nullptr) {
    std::cout << star->data;
    star = star->next;
  }
}
```

or something to that effect. You should consider taking `root1` as `node**` instead and passing it a pointer to `root` from `main`. That way, you won't have to remember to assign the return value to `root` each time.